Cannot SSH to my server, systetmd-login fails
I cannot SSH on my remote server (Ubuntu 22). When I try, it loads indefinitely. Here is the ouptut of a ssh -v:
Authenticated to x.x.x.x ([x.x.x.x]:22) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem

I looked it up and came across this post and a few others.
I tried running systemctl restart systemd-logind but it just times out:

(running from a VM so I cannot copy/paste, sorry).
As for journalctl, here it is:

I also tried to comment out this line: #session optional pam_systemd.so in /etc/pam.d/common-session and to add UseDNS no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, according to different forum answsers.
I read somewhere that /etc/var/log/btmp could be too big and crash, but mine does not seem to be too large: 
Also, it should be noted that after running systemctl restart systemd-logind, sometimes the SSH connection returns for a few seconds and stops again.
Many thanks in advance for your help.
Edit: output of ssh -vvvv: too long for the post, please find it here. (replaced ip with x.x.x.x)

Add output of ssh -vvvv. That is 4 vs to get more verbose output.

I didn't know that. You can find it here: https://justpaste.it/8k0la
